# Bad UX for new user when told to move post to other SE 'site' but can only post 1 per 40 min

Tags: feature-request, support, new-users

I'd like to recommend a code change in Stack Exchange to prevent a bad user experience that happened to me, a new user.

I posted a question on the [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com) site, and was told it would be better in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

So I deleted my post and tried to re-post the same text to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but got the error:

> "You can only post once every 40 minutes."

This gave me the feels that I was punished for doing the right thing.

If a user deletes his or her own post, that user should be able to post immediately in a different 'site' of SE so they don't have a bad first impression. If you're trying to stop spammers, cool, set a limit of 3 deletes and re-posts in case they keep getting told to move it a couple of times.

Then it made me do a CAPTCHA puzzle even though I'm logged in. Also lame. (I use a VPN set at my router level, which should be considered normal for people who like privacy but most websites don't consider it normal which is very annoying.) Is there a reason to require a CAPTCHA when someone is logged in?

Every security or anti-spam feature you can add could potentially increase friction with legit users; that's something to always keep in mind when trying to cope with a spammer issue by using automation.

Comment: Was the question time critical, making it unnecessarily hard to wait 40 minutes? Those minutes could be spend familiarizing yourself with the target site, perhaps your question was already answered there or you got a bad referral.

Comment: There is a major spam problem on SE that requires measures. Removing those will not improve the quality of the network overall. Considering many spammers use throw-away accounts, your proposed alternative would not help much.

Comment: I appreciate your responses. It wasn't time-critical; it just rubbed me the wrong way. I understand spam can be pretty bad. Thank you for considering and reading, anyway!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are we allowed to ask only one question per 40 minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284722/why-are-we-allowed-to-ask-only-one-question-per-40-minutes)

Comment: Even considering spam, it seems like it would be reasonable to implement *something* along these lines which provides a better UX for new users who are trying to do the right thing. I definitely wouldn't want to open this up completely, but a single delete and repost on a different site within 80 minutes would be reasonable and result in the same overall rate limitation. Another possibility would be to allow the OP to initiate a *single* migration of an unanswered question to a site on which they A) have an account and B) on which they are able to post questions.

Comment: @gnat How is a [tag:feature-request] asking for a change in the limitation a duplicate of a [tag:discussion] which asks for the reasons behind the limitation? Sure, the feature request should address the reasons for the limitation, but asking for change isn't a duplicate of the reasons. It might be marked as [tag:status-declined] as a result of those reasons, but that's not duplication.

Comment: Thank you, Makyen. Yes, I'm not asking to remove all anti-spam features; just to improve them so they don't give a bad impression to a newbie trying to do the right thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please reduce the timer for \_cross site\_ consecutive questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296242/282094)   
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296970/282094        
  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286069/282094

Comment: Reason for the wait times chosen: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/3648282

Comment: "So I deleted my post" - The proper action would have been to request it be migrated to the proper community.  This way you wouldn't have a delete question.  Of course knowing that questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope on Unix Stack Exchange website would have been preferred.